# How to show a color-coded country map (with city boundaries) in Aframe

Tags: d3.js, aframe, topojson

Following my previous question:[Load json map into aframe by aframe-geo-projection-component created by earthlinginteractive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72960328/load-json-map-into-aframe-by-aframe-geo-projection-component-created-by-earthlin/72963611#72963611)

Now, I am trying to find a way to show different geometries (country or city) in AFrame each with a different color,
looking for something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvfzk.png).

I do not mind which library or approach are used, Found [this](https://ukalpa.com/use-d3js-to-show-the-map-of-new-zealand-regional-council-boundaries) but not sure how to convert this D3.js to Aframe. However as the community bot asked me to provide more details, I have put the code that I am working on [below](https://fluttering-midnight-team.glitch.me/indexExtrude.html). Not sure which part I need to modify to have such a color coded map but I am working on that. Again, any working example works for me even if someone can show what I need to modify in the below code.

```
<!--  https://github.com/EarthlingInteractive/aframe-geo-projection-component 
  https://earthlinginteractive.github.io/aframe-geo-projection-component/  -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>A-Frame Geo Projection Component - U.S. Population 2017 (est.)</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Visualization of estimated U.S. population by state in 2017"></meta>
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.7.1/aframe.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/donmccurdy/aframe-extras/v3.12.4/dist/aframe-extras.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/super-hands@2.1.0/dist/super-hands.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-queue.v3.js"></script>
    <script src="https://earthlinginteractive.github.io/aframe-geo-projection-component/dist/aframe-geo-projection-component.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
  AFRAME.registerComponent('geo-extrude-population-renderer', {
    dependencies: ['geo-projection'],
    schema: {
      maxExtrudeHeight: {
        default: 2
      }
    },
    init: function () {
      this.system = this.el.sceneEl.systems['geo-projection'];
      this.geoProjectionComponent = this.el.components['geo-projection'];
      this.geoJsonReady = this.geoJsonReady.bind(this);
      // Wait for geoJson to finish loading to avoid race conditions
      this.el.addEventListener('geo-src-loaded', this.geoJsonReady);
    },
    update: function (oldData) {
      if (!this.geoProjectionComponent.geoJson) {
        return;
      }
      if (this.data.maxExtrudeHeight !== oldData.maxExtrudeHeight) {
        this.geoJsonReady();
      }
    },
    geoJsonReady: function () {
      // Now kick off loading the data
      d3.queue()
        .defer(d3.csv, 'https://cdn.glitch.global/c153e3cf-7430-444d-9897-4e97f1ef8d35/us-population-2017.csv?v=1657704183925', function (d) {
          return {
            state: d.state,
            population: +d.population
          }
        })
        .defer(d3.csv, 'https://cdn.glitch.global/c153e3cf-7430-444d-9897-4e97f1ef8d35/us-state-county-geocodes-v2016.csv?v=1657704190160')
        .await(this.onDataLoaded.bind(this));
    },
    onDataLoaded: function(error, populationData, geocodes) {
      if (error) throw error;
      var stateFips = geocodes.filter(function (row) {
        return row['Summary_Level'] === '040'
      });
      var maxPopulation = d3.max(populationData, function (d) {
        return d.population;
      });
      var populationByFipsCode = populationData.reduce(function (accum, d) {
        var fipsForState = stateFips.find(function (fipsRow) { return fipsRow['Area_Name'] === d.state; });
        var fipsCode = fipsForState['State_Code_FIPS'];
        accum[fipsCode] = d.population;
        return accum;
      }, {});
      this.render(populationByFipsCode, maxPopulation, this.data.maxExtrudeHeight);
    },
    render: function (populationByFipsCode, maxPopulation, maxExtrudeHeight) {
      if (!populationByFipsCode) return;
      var material = [];
      var extrudeGeometry = null;
      var stateOutlineVertices = [];
      // Split the geoJson into features and render each one individually so that we can set a different
      // extrusion height for each based on the population.
      this.geoProjectionComponent.geoJson.features.forEach(function (feature) {
        var population = populationByFipsCode[feature.id];
        var extrudeAmount = (population / maxPopulation) * maxExtrudeHeight;
        var material="#999999";
        const extrudeSettings = {
          amount: extrudeAmount,
          bevelEnabled: false
        };
//Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
        var mapRenderContext = this.system.renderToContext(feature, this.geoProjectionComponent.projection);
        const stateShapes = mapRenderContext.toShapes();

        // Gather the outline of the state and set the height of the outline to the extrude level
        // so that the top of the state is outlined
        stateOutlineVertices = stateOutlineVertices.concat(mapRenderContext.toVertices(extrudeAmount));

        // Merge all the extruded feature geometries together for better rendering performance
        // Need to use ExtrudeGeometry here instead of ExtrudeBufferGeometry because the latter doesn't merge properly
        // in this version of Three.js
        var extrudedFeatureGeometry = new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry(stateShapes, extrudeSettings);
        if (!extrudeGeometry) {
          extrudeGeometry = extrudedFeatureGeometry;
        } else {
          extrudeGeometry.merge(extrudedFeatureGeometry);
        }
      }.bind(this));

      // Convert the extrude geometry into a buffer geometry for better rendering performance
      var extrudeBufferGeometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
      extrudeBufferGeometry.fromGeometry(extrudeGeometry);

      var sideMaterial = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial( { color: 0xaaafff } );
      var extrudedMap = new THREE.Mesh(extrudeBufferGeometry, [material, sideMaterial]);
      this.el.setObject3D('map', extrudedMap);

      var stateOutlineGeometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
      stateOutlineGeometry.addAttribute('position', new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute(stateOutlineVertices, 3));
      var stateOutlineMaterial = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color: 0xcccaaa } );
      var stateOutlines = new THREE.LineSegments(stateOutlineGeometry, stateOutlineMaterial);
      this.el.setObject3D('lines', stateOutlines);
    }
  });
</script>
<a-scene>
    <a-assets>
        <a-asset-item id="json-us" src="https://unpkg.com/us-atlas@1/us/10m.json" />
    </a-assets>
    <a-sky color="#ECECEC"></a-sky>
    <a-entity id="map"
              rotation="-90 0 0"
               material="color: #123456;"
              topojson-loader="src: #json-us; topologyObject: states;"
              geo-projection="
                  projection: geoIdentity;
                  height: 6;
                  width: 10;"
              geo-extrude-population-renderer
    >
    </a-entity>
    <a-locomotor>
        <a-entity hand-controls="left" super-hands></a-entity>
        <a-entity hand-controls="right" super-hands></a-entity>
    </a-locomotor>
</a-scene>
</body>
</html>
<!--material="color: #123456;"-->
```

getting this error as well if I use aframe 1.3.0:

```
Uncaught TypeError: extrudeBufferGeometry.fromGeometry is not a function
at i.render ((index):104:29)
at i.onDataLoaded ((index):66:12)
at Queue._call (d3-queue.v3.js:43:54)
at maybeNotify (d3-queue.v3.js:120:7)
at d3-queue.v3.js:91:12
at Object.<anonymous> (d3.v4.js:11470:86)
at Dispatch.call (d3.v4.js:792:72)
at XMLHttpRequest.respond (d3.v4.js:11395:13)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45853966/d3-js-graph-dashboard-conversion-to-png-jpg-pdf 
Are you looking for this?

Comment: Not sure how this is related to my problem

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.